# TypeError: message.guild.emojis.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making emojis command for discord bot but it throws an error
**TypeError: `message.guild.emojis.map` is not a function**
whats the problem?

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'emojis')) {
        const List = message.guild.emojis.map(e => e.toString()).join(" ");
        const EmojiList = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Emojis') 
            .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL) 
            .setColor('RANDOM') 
            .setDescription(List) 
            .setFooter(message.guild.name) 
        message.channel.send(EmojiList) 
    }
});
```

Does anyone see where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `cache` after the `emojis`. This was introduced in v12.

```js
message.guild.emojis.cache.map(e => e.toString()).join(" ")
```